# OR multiple filtering clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

There is a function in clojure `every-pred` that checks for multiple filtering

```
(every-pred integer? pos?)
```

Is there any function that could check if the sequence has true for predicate1 or predicate2

```
(or predicate1? predicate2?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`some-fn`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some-fn):

```
(filter (some-fn predicate-1? predicate-2?) [x y z])
```

Note that if you [look up `every-pred` on ClojureDocs.org](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/every-pred), `some-fn` is listed in the "See Also" section.